# I have an iframe which content I need Google to index. Is this possible?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, search

I have a classifieds website.

The index.html has a form:

```
     <form action="php_page" target="iframe" etc...>
```

The iframe displays the results, and the php_page builds the results for the iframe. Basically the php_page builds a table containing the results from a mysql db, and outputs it.

My problem is that this doesn't get indexed by google.

How can I solve this?

The reason I used an Iframe in the first place was to avoid page-reloading when hitting submit.

Ajax couldn't be used due to various reasons I wont go into here.

Any ideas what to do?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have a sitemap with URLS to all the classifieds also, but I don't think this guarantees google to spider those URLS.

Comment: Why don't you use $_GET variables (maybe discouraged in some ways by Google) or load some default data without submit?

Comment: I don't understand fabrik, please specify what you mean... I do use GET method in the form, if thats what you mean.

Comment: you could avoid the iframe, placing your initial output inside the page (so it can be indexed) and then using ajax to refresh data when you hit your submit. (sorry i read later your ajax note)

Comment: So there is no other way than using ajax to display the results in a way so that it gets indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to make the google spider crawl the results of a search form is not really the right approach.

Assuming you want google.com users to find your classifieds ads by searching google, the best approach is to create a set of static html pages from the ads, and link them (not invisibly) from elsewhere on your site (probably best from the home page - but such a link can be in a footer or something else unobtrusive)

They can also be linked to from your [sitemap XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) (you do have a sitemap XML file don't you?)

Note: the `<iframe>` doesn't really come into this. Or Ajax.

Comment: I do have a sitemap offcourse. So you are saying I could build up a "catalogue" of all ads on the page, and that way have links to all classifieds manually as well? Btw, check my update.

Comment: Absolutely..***(padding chars because SO makes me do that...)

Comment: Sounds good, I might just do that. Also, came to think of it, this way I can also make my website work for users with js disabled (as my form uses js to work mainly). Thanks!

Comment: Re the update: If the page is only in the sitemap, but not otherwise spiderable, the Google spider may well ignore it. Best to have both routes to your ads available.

Comment: Re the js-disabled thing: yes that is best practice. And the Google spider loves best practice. If you make a site that is progressively enhanced or degrades gracefully in such a way as it works in the most limited browsers, chances are the google spider will love you for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make any webspider fill out and submit forms.

Workaround: Every night, create a dump of the database and save the HTML to a file. Create a link from `index.html` to that file. Use CSS classes to make the link invisible. This way, Google will pick it up but users won't see it.

Comment: The google spider is clever enough to know when a link is invisible. I think there is a strong chance that would be treated as a 'black hat' technique.

Comment: Hmmm... I see what you mean. Still I think that my approach is a good start.